# String cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Tags: android, casting, android-button

I’m trying to add Buttons dynamically and these in a row.
In the summary of my code below I have this error:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

I have been searching in similar error messages, but I can’t solve mine.
Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
   a=a+a;
  FrameLayout.LayoutParams a = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(262, 146);
  a.leftMargin = coorX; coorX = coorX + 250; 
  FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
  layout.addView (((Button)boton.get(i)),a); // here's the error
  ((Button)boton.get(i)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
          switch (((Button)view).getId()){
             case 1: recuadro("wǒ", 1); break;
             case 2: recuadro("hěn", 2); break;
             case 3: recuadro("ne", 3); break;
             case 4: recuadro("nĭ ne?", 4); break;
             case 5: recuadro("yě", 5); break;
          }
  });

}
```

Comment: It's like you are trying to transform apples into bananas.

Comment: The solution is to keep passing apples where it wants apples.

Comment: Pass strings to strings, Buttons to Buttons. Whatever to whatever of the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to create a Button instead of adding a String

```
new Button("Here the string");
```

in your case:

```
new Button(boton(i))
```

**EDIT**

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
   a=a+a;
  FrameLayout.LayoutParams a = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(262, 146);
  a.leftMargin = coorX; coorX = coorX + 250; 
  FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
  Button buttonToAdd = new Button(boton.get(i));
  layout.addView (buttonToAdd,a); // here's the error
  buttonToAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
          switch (((Button)view).getId()){
             case 1: recuadro("wǒ", 1); break;
             case 2: recuadro("hěn", 2); break;
             case 3: recuadro("ne", 3); break;
             case 4: recuadro("nĭ ne?", 4); break;
             case 5: recuadro("yě", 5); break;
          }
  });

}
```

if im not wrong its like this.

Comment: Sorry, I’m not an expert, but I don’t know where and how to create a Button instead of adding a String.

Answer (score 0):

`boton` is a list of strings, and you're casting its elements into `Buttons`. Hence, the error message `java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.widget.Button`.

Comment: In that case, what can I do to transform my String-Buttons into Buttons?

Comment: You need to create buttons. Instead of `layout.addView (((Button)boton.get(i)),a);`, do `Button button = new Button(boton.get(i));` and then  `layout.addView (button,a);` and then do `button.setOnClickListener(..... the rest of your code)`

Comment: I have applied tour suggestion, but in the code appear an error with the message:
    Button (…) cannot be applied to java.lang.Object
What could it be? Would be my code now like this?:
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);

    Button button = new Button(boton.get(i)); // YOUR SUGGESTION
layout.addView (button,a)

    (Button)boton.get(i)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    …

Comment: Mate that was half of my suggestion. You missed the other half.